# Bootstrap form row width

Tags: css, forms

I'm trying to build a form looking like this:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nojo3Lx4/4)

Problem is that the row is much wider than the actual content, so the container get streched way to much.

Anyone got a clue on how to reduce the rows width to the actual content?

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form class="">

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="passord" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <textarea class="form-control" cols="5" maxLength="500" />
      </div>
    </div>




  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this resizable fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/nojo3Lx4/10/), when you make the viewport wider the `input`s should remain on their column size without filling the entire viewport row.

EDIT: `.col` classes would be bordered (if you don't want a border taking up all 12 columns as with `.container` class), `.container` will always occupy the full 12 column grid.

Like the picture below shows, you are using 6 columns (half the grid), so another 6 `col` element could go at it's right, this is why if you border the `.container`, it will always show all 12 column `width`.

[image]

Comment: i wanted to have the two input in one line

Comment: I edited the JSFIDDLE in the first post, so you can better see what I mean. The "box" i want to surround the form with is way to wide.

Comment: The solution works fine for me but why is there html in the textarea?

Comment: `<textarea>` is missing a closing tag `</textarea>`, I'll edit it as well. Should be `<textarea class="form-control" cols="5" maxLength="500"></textarea>`

Comment: worked out, but why is every other tag fine immediate closing of the tag but not the textarea?

Comment: Basically `<textarea></textarea>` is a container and `<textarea />` is not. For example, `<textarea>demo test</textarea>` would be the default displaying text.